# Not able to run iOS Appium tests when using node

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver, appium, appium-ios

I've been running my iOS appium tests using the Appium.app without issue.

I want to try using node + appium package instead but I'm running into the error displayed below.

I've tried reinstalling node and the appium and wd packages but the issue still persists. I've allowed OSX to accept incoming connections from node as well.

No issues found with my environment using: *appium-doctor --ios*

Appium log:

```
[Appium] Welcome to Appium v1.5.1 (REV c330ee9862bbc0db7d604e3b395cd1226417a9b9)
[Appium] Appium REST http interface listener started on 0.0.0.0:4723
[HTTP] --> POST /wd/hub/session {"desiredCapabilities":{"platformName":"iOS","platformVersion":"9.3","deviceName":"iPhone 6s","app":"/Users/User/Downloads/AppToTestSimulator.app (5).zip","autoAcceptAlerts":"false","appium_version":"1.5.1"}}
[MJSONWP] Calling AppiumDriver.createSession() with args: [{"platformName":"iOS","platformVersion":"9.3","deviceName":"iPhone 6s","app":"/Users/User/Downloads/AppToTestSimulator.app (5).zip","aut...
[Appium] Creating new IosDriver session
[Appium] Capabilities:
[Appium]   platformName: 'iOS'
[Appium]   platformVersion: '9.3'
[Appium]   deviceName: 'iPhone 6s'
[Appium]   app: '/Users/User/Downloads/AppToTestSimulator.app (5).zip'
[Appium]   autoAcceptAlerts: 'false'
[Appium]   appium_version: '1.5.1'
[BaseDriver] Capability 'autoAcceptAlerts' changed from string to boolean. This may cause unexpected behavior
[BaseDriver] The following capabilities were provided, but are not recognized by appium: appium_version.
[BaseDriver] Session created with session id: bc760657-425f-4b2a-a6a7-b0e96b3f7c01
[debug] [iOS] Not auto-detecting udid.
[BaseDriver] Using local app '/Users/User/Downloads/AppToTestSimulator.app (5).zip'
[debug] [BaseDriver] Copying local zip to tmp dir
[debug] [BaseDriver] Unzipping /var/folders/6v/w_s4j0fj27b1lnk8rnj0k4thvgjb4k/T/2016312-21862-1sug2zc/appium-app.zip
[debug] [BaseDriver] Testing zip archive: /var/folders/6v/w_s4j0fj27b1lnk8rnj0k4thvgjb4k/T/2016312-21862-1sug2zc/appium-app.zip
[BaseDriver] Unzipped local app to '/var/folders/6v/w_s4j0fj27b1lnk8rnj0k4thvgjb4k/T/2016312-21862-1sug2zc/AppToTest.app'
[debug] [iOS] Removing any remaining instruments sockets
[debug] [iOS] Cleaned up instruments socket /var/folders/6v/w_s4j0fj27b1lnk8rnj0k4thvgjb4k/T/instruments_sock
[debug] [iOS] Setting Xcode version
[debug] [iOS] Xcode version set to 7.3
[debug] [iOS] Setting iOS SDK Version
[debug] [iOS] iOS SDK Version set to 9.3
[debug] [iOS] Checking whether instruments supports our device string
[debug] [Instruments] Getting list of devices instruments supports
[debug] [Instruments] Instruments is at: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/instruments
[debug] [Instruments] Available devices: Apple TV 1080p (9.2) [A350CABB-DB34-4933-8C8D-94BE4E695BD9] (Simulator),iPad 2 (8.4) [8FF96C8F-5BAB-4863-945C-62C92F9F7C91] (Simulator),iPad 2 (9.3) [74017AF7-1E44-4708-BA84-3BD09E5A50AD] (Simulator),iPad Air (8.4) [018AD91A-560B-475B-8E59-4633D4E4F70F] (Simulator),iPad Air (9.3) [441357FB-6D52-41E4-8AA3-682BE3A1CA03] (Simulator),iPad Air 2 (9.3) [5D925D0C-7FA2-4CEE-BE47-85E0DACFA67A] (Simulator),iPad Pro (9.3) [BADE2306-4190-44F8-A88A-21BC19137589] (Simulator),iPad Retina (8.4) [6436FE08-5493-4E95-9AB0-8CDB5EB14FC9] (Simulator),iPad Retina (9.3) [EDDB468C-EA62-443F-B273-FEC00F96FA6B] (Simulator),iPhone 4s (8.4) [DA7DF90E-7EB9-4199-ABE8-1DF2B89C593B] (Simulator),iPhone 4s (9.3) [64305631-8F8E-4DFF-BF10-6254B30C885A] (Simulator),iPhone 5 (8.4) [A2E02B24-E960-4182-8B1D-5EE633E64E4D] (Simulator),iPhone 5 (9.3) [3610DBC3-1F8E-48F3-8E86-93E2DCD28B3C] (Simulator),iPhone 5s (8.4) [385EBC18-FBEE-43D3-8A9F-ED6FB9E17D99] (Simulator),iPhone 5s (9.3) [1177F60B-F9A5-4D6E-B9E7-00F172ECB09C] (Simulator),iPhone 6 (8.4) [1CB02197-3B62-444F-B745-11884344D226] (Simulator),iPhone 6 (9.3) [F05E7BCD-1A83-4F64-8C43-9D6320116780] (Simulator),iPhone 6 Plus (8.4) [4683EB66-6644-4D3B-997B-6A417C9C7C5C] (Simulator),iPhone 6 Plus (9.3) [72630DFB-B5B1-4D79-B7C3-DAF39E1EE0F6] (Simulator),iPhone 6s (9.3) [4116EA28-E0C2-45F2-A201-22C3B1CAFBE3] (Simulator),iPhone 6s (9.3) + Apple Watch - 38mm (2.2) [D8DD477B-D5C4-4575-A83B-C5D95D40A1E1] (Simulator),iPhone 6s Plus (9.3) [7716603A-2DAE-439D-A59A-AA561C90D888] (Simulator),iPhone 6s Plus (9.3) + Apple Watch - 42mm (2.2) [A4FE07E7-4CC4-4507-AE70-E07B7EC0DE21] (Simulator)
[iOSSim] Retrieving device name string for Xcode version 7.3
[debug] [iOSSim] Getting device string from options: {"deviceName":"iPhone 6s","platformVersion":"9.3","forceIphone":false,"forceIpad":false}
[debug] [iOSSim] Fixing device. Changed from 'iPhone 6s' to 'iPhone 6s (9.3) ['
[debug] [iOSSim] Final device string is 'iPhone 6s (9.3) ['
[debug] [iOS] iOS sim UDID is 4116EA28-E0C2-45F2-A201-22C3B1CAFBE3
[iOSSim] Constructing iOS simulator for Xcode version 7.3
[debug] [iOS] No language specified. Using default strings
[debug] [iOS] Strings file not found. Looking in 'en.lproj' directory
[iOS] Could not file localizable strings file 'Localizable.strings'!
[debug] [ios-app-utils] Getting bundle ID from app
[iOS] Extracted bundleID: us.AppToTest.AppToTestPreprod from app: /var/folders/6v/w_s4j0fj27b1lnk8rnj0k4thvgjb4k/T/2016312-21862-1sug2zc/AppToTest.app
[debug] [iOS] Creating instruments
[debug] [UIAuto] Preparing bootstrap code
[debug] [UIAuto] Dynamic bootstrap dir: /Users/User/Library/Application Support/appium/bootstrap
[debug] [UIAuto] Dynamic env: {"nodePath":"/usr/local/bin/node","commandProxyClientPath":"/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-ios-driver/node_modules/appium-uiauto/build/lib/bin/command-proxy-client.js","instrumentsSock":"/var/folders/6v/w_s4j0fj27b1lnk8rnj0k4thvgjb4k/T/instruments_sock","interKeyDelay":null,"justLoopInfinitely":false,"autoAcceptAlerts":false,"autoDismissAlerts":false,"sendKeyStrategy":"oneByOne"}
...bug] [UIAuto] Dynamic bootstrap code: // This file is automatically generated. Do not manually modify!
[debug] [UIAuto] Dynamic bootstrap path: /Users/User/Library/Application Support/appium/bootstrap/bootstrap-f8e8ef362019f9d8.js
[debug] [UIAuto] Reusing dynamic bootstrap: /Users/User/Library/Application Support/appium/bootstrap/bootstrap-f8e8ef362019f9d8.js
[debug] [iOS] User specified default device, letting instruments launch it
[debug] [iOS] Running ios sim reset flow
[debug] [iOS] Killing the simulator
[debug] [iOSSim] Killing all iOS Simulators
[MJSONWP] Encountered internal error running command: Error: Condition unmet after 60011 ms. Timing out.
    at spin$ (lib/asyncbox.js:118:13)
    at tryCatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/asyncbox/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:67:40)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke [as _invoke] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/asyncbox/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:294:22)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/asyncbox/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:100:21)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/asyncbox/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:136:37)
    at run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/asyncbox/node_modules/babel-runtime/node_modules/core-js/library/modules/es6.promise.js:89:39)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/asyncbox/node_modules/babel-runtime/node_modules/core-js/library/modules/es6.promise.js:100:28
    at nextTickCallbackWith0Args (node.js:420:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:349:13)
[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session 500 62780 ms - 180
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by reinstalling x-code and performing the 'sudo authorize-ios' command. The latter was probably the only thing that was required.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, and tried the same - I removed Xcode entirely (including command line tools, library files, etc) and reinstalled, but still have the exact same issue.

I would describe the same as you - we've been running appium tests for a year with no issues like this, but as soon as we switched to npm for appium 1.5 rather than just downloading the repo and running reset.sh for previous appium versions, suddenly i have exactly your stacktrace at exactly that point in the log

and like you, `appium-doctor` shows no issues

and like you, I've already performed `sudo authorize-ios`

Comment: I ran into this issue again after installing the iOS 9.2 simulator and trying to use it. I resolved the issue by restarting my machine and running sudo authorize-ios again. You might want to try keeping xcode closed if you still have issues.